# Start Azure Web Job based on Timer AND new message on Service Bus?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azureservicebus

I want to know if it is possible to have a web job run, triggered either by a new message on an Azure Service Bus (topic) OR when a timer occurs.  I know I could create two separate web jobs, but am hoping to combine the two since 99% of the logic will be the same.

Example on how we start a web job when message is ready in Service Bus:

```
[Singleton]
        public  void ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("%TopicName%", "%SubscriptionName%")] BrokeredMessage message, TextWriter log)
        {
// Processing code here
}
```

Example on how we start a web job based on a timer:

```
public static void ProcessByTimer([TimerTrigger("00:00:30", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo timerInfo, TextWriter log)
        {
            // Processing code here
        }
```

Note, I tried having the web job have both methods, but it never seemed to enter the timer method, only the service bus triggered method.

Kind regards,

Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can most certainly have both methods in a single WebJob, and that's the way to do it. If your TimerTrigger isn't firing, I suggest that you make sure that you have config.UseTimers() in your Program.cs file. If you do not call the UseTimers method, no TimerTrigger will ever fire.

Comment: That's great.  Yeah, I had forgotton to set UseTimers() in my test.